# Applications to make photo collages

Tags: software-recommendation, photo-management

Is there a good application where I can make collages using my photo collection  on Ubuntu 12.04?

I Saw [this link](http://maketecheasier.com/5-free-tools-to-create-collages-from-your-pictures/2010/02/23) ,but couldn't find any of them in my Ubuntu software centre or the instructions to add the PPA to get them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite a nice, simple tool for creating collages is [`fotowall`](http://www.enricoros.com/opensource/fotowall/); it is available in the repositories as version 0.9-7, although there isn't a ppa for a more recent version and there doesn't seem to have been much activity on the [github](https://github.com/enricoros/fotowall) page. However, the original developer, Enrico Ros, does note [at his site](http://www.enricoros.com/opensource/fotowall/) that two universities are working on some elements of a future version 1.

Nevertheless, `fotowall` is a very useful program for creating collages; many different canvas sizes and layouts can be used and the pictures added to that canvas can be resized and arranged in many different ways. Text can be added, for example, to the base of pictures or you can have separate text boxes anywhere on your canvas.

Special effects like shadow or blur can also be turned on or off for each picture. It is possible to control how the pictures overlap and which ones are brought to the foreground or sent to the background. If you select a photo you can even warp it so it appears 3d- just click a photo and then click the red dot you can see in the top toolbar (as in the screenshot), and move it off axis. I find that it's best to just experiment and see what's possible with the program.

[image]

You can save the canvas as a `.fotowall` document, which you can continue working on later, or click the export button at the top right of the screen and then save it as an image, a wallpaper, or print directly from the program. The full list of options can be seen in the screenshot below; you may notice that there is no option to export as pdf, but that's no problem as you can just use imagemagick and run `convert myfotowall.bmp myfotowall.pdf` and specify any options if you need to.

[image]

Comment: Not available anymore in the Ubuntu software repos, at least for 16.04.

Answer (score 9):

I recently found two new software for that, [G'MIC Montage](http://blog.patdavid.net/2014/05/gmic-montage.html) and [PhotoCollage](https://github.com/adrienverge/PhotoCollage).

Comment: Photocollage is very nice!!! Recomended!

Comment: +1 for GMic. Not only was more flexible and worked better than photocollage. Also is [open source](https://github.com/dtschump/gmic-community) and it's on the Ubuntu software repos.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out how to install and use GMic: `apt install gmic gimp-gmic`. Then GMic appears in the list of filters within gimp. Load images into gimp as layers, and run the filter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any application for managing pictures : [GIMP](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gimp/), [Inkscape](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/inkscape/) (just like Kalle said), [Pinta](http://pinta-project.com) ([how to install](http://pinta-project.com/pinta/HowTo.Installing-Pinta.ashx))...

> I Saw [this link](http://maketecheasier.com/5-free-tools-to-create-collages-from-your-pictures/2010/02/23) ,but couldn't find any of them in my Ubuntu software
>   center or the instructions to add the PPA to get them.

Picture2Life, Photovisi and Fotonea can be used only on the website. Picasa for Linux does not exist anymore. You can [download Shape Collage here](http://www.shapecollage.com/download). For Linux, you can <del>use the Java version or</del> download the tarball (they no longer use Java).

Answer (score 0):

A solid application that I found for creating collages is called Fotowall.  Easy to use, versitile and quick.  It also was eay to use.  Here is the [link](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/fotowall/) if anyone wants more information.